# Controlling when the subscription check happens in azure API management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management, Azure portal provides a way to configure the "subscription required" in the setting of the APIs. However is it possible to control when this validation occurs. Currently it happens before it hits the inbound policies. Would I be able to set it to happen after certain inbound policies are executed. Else is there a way to control the trigger of the validation from the policy level?

Answer (score 1):

Was answered on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/360. To quote myself:

Yeah, we heard this scenario before. Please, submit it here: http://aka.ms/apimwish For now though subscription key is required to be passed either as a header or as a query parameter. You can make your API/product not require subscription key at all and do your own auth check in policy followed by rate-limit. This is usually done for certificate or OAuth.